# Onclick() event: random appearance of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, onclick

my code shows an image in the centre of the webpage, and does 2 different actions if click is outside or inside image. I want to change the position of the image randomly at every onclick() event (no matter if the click is in or out), while staying within the page initial size.

The two actions are correctly done, but the image doesn't change position. Can someone tell me what i should change?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>random position</title>
  </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
   $(window).height();
   $(window).width(); 
  </script>

  <body>

    <style>

    #myImage { position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;  }
    </style>

    <script>
function moveImg() {
  var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

  var width = $(img).width();
  var height = $(img).height();


  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var offset = $(img).offset();
    if (e.target === img) {
      action 1;
    } 
    else {
     action 2;
    }
    // GENERATE RANDOM LOCATION IN BOTH CASES
    img.offset.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.width()- 0) + 0);
    img.offset.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.height()- 0) + 0);


  }, false);
}
    </script>
      <img id="myImage"  src="img.gif" onclick="moveImg()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does ``action 1;`` and ``action 2;`` mean? My guess is you get a JS error when this code is executed. You also keep adding more and more event listeners on each click ...

Comment: no if I run the same code without the random position part is works fine. Before I was using another method to generate a rondom posion (below). it worked, but it was not fully correct: /* var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    img.style.top = x + "px";
    img.style.left = y + "px";*/

Comment: Sorry here is the code I was using to change position: var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

    img.style.top = x + "px";
    img.style.left = y + "px";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here. You're calling a function when a user clicks, but within that function you're assigning an event listener for a click on that image. That doesn't make much sense to keep adding more and more event listeners on each click. I changed the code below to demonstrate adding an event listener once, not on every click.

Second, the `action 1` and `action 2` don't really make sense. I commented those out since I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish there.

You were also incorrectly attempting to change top and left attributes of the image. I corrected that to use the `css()` function.

The below code shows the changes in the javascript. Or you could [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/sw27d4sp/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

  var width = $(img).width();
  var height = $(img).height();


  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var offset = $(img).offset();
    if (e.target === img) {
      //action 1;
    } 
    else {
     //action 2;
    }
    // GENERATE RANDOM LOCATION IN BOTH CASES
    $(img).css({
    top: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height()),
    left: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width())});
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: Hi Sam, yes action 1 and action 2 are just names for what I am doing in that if-else statement. Thank you for adjusting the event listener, but your code still doesn't solve my main problem of moving the image (randomly) within the initial page size. How could I do that?

Comment: If I use the code below, the image is always shown on the right part of the screen, whereas I want the image to appear in any part of the screen with equal probability                                                                               
                                                                                                            
left: Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width()- width) + 0),
top: Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height()- height) + 0)});

Comment: @Gigi What do you mean "the right part of the screen." I just checked and it should actually work. Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1, so multiplying it by the window width/height chooses a random location within the window. I just tested it and it seems to work. I attached a fiddle that should demonstrate it working

Comment: I mean that the image is initially displayed in the centre of the screen and, whenever I click on it, it always stays on the right and below with respect to the initial central position. Therefore, I think that there is a mistake in the way I assign the new top and left value? I hope this make sense to you..

Comment: And I think that your page size increases because you swapped top and left (when using height and width as max size)?

Comment: @Gigi Yup definitely mixed those two up, my mistake. And I believe that's just the randomness of  Math.random(). In the fiddle I moved the image to be way further into the window (top: 300, left 300) and you can more clearly see that it doesn't stay to the right of the initial position (also added a console statement to see the position)